# bash not always trapping ^C when exec used

Tags: bash, exec

In the following test I see that on bash 4.2.25 (ubuntu 12.10) my trap function is called when I hit ^C. On 4.3.11 (ubuntu 14.10) the program exits without calling the trap. I'm at a loss as to why this is. I'm assuming it is not a bash bug and just my exec usage is wrong. Any ideas?

```
#!/bin/bash

mytrap()
{
    echo TRAPPED
}

exec &> >(tee -a logfile)
trap "mytrap" 0 1 2 15 ERR SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT
sleep 1000
```

Taking tee out of the equation just to rule that out, I see no change:

```
exec &> >(cat -)

ubuntu12# ./test.sh
^CTRAPPED
TRAPPED
TRAPPED

ubuntu14# ./test.sh
^C
```

Comment: I may have answered my own question. Using tee -i to get tee to ignore the signal seems to work. Not sure why the interrupt handling is different between the two versions; but it does seem that perhaps tee is stealing the signal in the bad case. Sounds like a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Any chance your terminal on Ubuntu 14 is mapping Ctrl-C to "Copy"?  For instance, on my Fedora 12 box using gterm, I had to explicitly un-map Ctrl-C in Edit->Preferences->Shortcuts in order to use Ctrl-C to kill a process.

Comment: No - identical terminals in both cases 8) Besides I can make it work fine by taking out the exec.